# How do I display dates when plotting in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this python code for displaying some numbers over time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

x = np.array([datetime.datetime(2013, 9, i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(1,5)], 
            dtype='datetime64')
y = np.array([1,-1,7,-3])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axhline(linewidth=4, color='r')
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph has the numbers 0.0 to 3.0 on the x-axis:

[image]

What is the simplest way to display dates instead of these numbers? Preferably in the format %b %d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to efiring](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2259), matplotlib does not support NumPy datetime64 objects (at least not yet).  Therefore, convert `x` to Python datetime.datetime objects:

```
x = x.astype(DT.datetime)
```

Next, you can specify the x-axis tick mark formatter like this:

```
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np

x = np.array([DT.datetime(2013, 9, i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(1,5)], 
            dtype='datetime64')
x = x.astype(DT.datetime)
y = np.array([1,-1,7,-3])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.axhline(linewidth=4, color='r')
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I only used the NumPy datetime64 object because I thought it would help so just x = np.array([datetime.datetime(2013, 9, i) for i in range(1,5)]) does it.