# Storing pure python datetime.datetime in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas

Since `matplotlib` doesn't support [either](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8113)`pandas.TimeStamp` [or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048792/how-do-i-display-dates-when-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot)`numpy.datetime64`, and  there are [no simple workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472548/pandas-scatter-plotting-datetime), I decided to convert a native pandas date column into a pure python `datetime.datetime` so that scatter plots are easier to make.

However:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-12-31')]})
t.dtypes # date    datetime64[ns], as expected
pure_python_datetime_array = t.date.dt.to_pydatetime() # works fine
t['date'] = pure_python_datetime_array # doesn't do what I hoped
t.dtypes # date    datetime64[ns] as before, no luck changing it
```

I'm guessing pandas auto-converts the pure python `datetime` produced by `to_pydatetime` into its native format. I guess it's convenient behavior in general, but is there a way to override it?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what format you actually want. Do you just want the date? Or also the time? See e.g. http://codrspace.com/szeitlin/biking-data-from-xml-to-plots-part-2/

Comment: I want the column `date` to have actual `datetime.datetime` objects. The ones that are returned by `to_pydatetime()` function. I don't want `TimeStamp` in that column because matplotlib can't make scatter plots with it.

Answer (score 4):

The use of [to_pydatetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-python-datetimes) is correct.

```
In [87]: t = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-12-31'), pd.to_datetime('2013-12-31')]})

In [88]: t.date.dt.to_pydatetime()
Out[88]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

When you assign it back to `t.date`, it automatically converts it back to `datetime64`

[pandas.Timestamp](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#overview) is a datetime subclass anyway :)

One way to do the plot is to convert the datetime to int64:

```
In [117]: t = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-12-31'), pd.to_datetime('2013-12-31')], 'sample_data': [1, 2]})

In [118]: t['date_int'] = t.date.astype(np.int64)

In [119]: t
Out[119]: 
        date  sample_data             date_int
0 2012-12-31            1  1356912000000000000
1 2013-12-31            2  1388448000000000000

In [120]: t.plot(kind='scatter', x='date_int', y='sample_data')
Out[120]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f3c852662d0>

In [121]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Another workaround is (to not use scatter, but ...):

```
In [126]: t.plot(x='date', y='sample_data', style='.')
Out[126]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f3c850f5750>
```

And, the last work around:

```
In [141]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [142]: t = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-12-31'), pd.to_datetime('2013-12-31')], 'sample_data': [100, 20000]})

In [143]: t
Out[143]: 
        date  sample_data
0 2012-12-31          100
1 2013-12-31        20000
In [144]: plt.scatter(t.date.dt.to_pydatetime()  , t.sample_data)
Out[144]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f3c84a10510>

In [145]: plt.show()
```

[image]

This has an issue at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8113), which is open as of now.

Comment: yes, I think the problem is that `t.date` is not the recommended way to reference a column named 'date'. It's a lot clearer to do `t['date']`.

Comment: I need the column to contain the pure python datetime.datetime objects. That way, the call to `df.plot(kind='scatter', ...)` will not fail.

Comment: @max Instead of `df.plot`, you can call `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` directly. I have updated the answer.

Comment: So there's no way to force pandas to store pure python `datetime.datetime` objects inside a `DataFrame`? Because that would have been the easiest workaround in my case, where the dataset isn't so big that I care about performance.

Comment: only the last workaround maintains the correct x axis labels and doesn't depend on the distance between x values being the same. i guess it's not that much extra typing, so probably the best (except won't work with `groupby`).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution with the `Series` class from `pandas`:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-12-31')]})
t.dtypes # date    datetime64[ns], as expected
pure_python_datetime_array = t.date.dt.to_pydatetime() # works fine
t['date'] = pd.Series(pure_python_datetime_array, dtype=object) # should do what you expect
t.dtypes # object, but the type of the date column is now correct! datetime
type(t.values[0, 0]) # datetime, now you can access the datetime object directly
```

Why is this working? My assumption is, that you force the `dtype` for the column `date` to be an `object`. So that pandas does not do any intern conversion from `datetime.datetime` to `datetime64`.

Correct me otherwise, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the steps look like this:

1. convert timezone with pytz
2. convert to_datetime with pandas and make that the index
3. plot and autoformat

Starting df looks like this:

[image: before converting timestamps]

1. `import pytz`
      `ts['posTime']=[x.astimezone(
                      pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')) for x in ts['posTime']]`

I can see that it worked because the timestamps changed format:

[image: after timezone conversion]

2. `sample['posTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(sample['posTime'])`

   `sample.index = sample['posTime']`

At this point, just plotting with pandas (which uses matplotlib under the hood) gives me a nice rotation and totally the wrong format:

[image: after pandas datetime conversion]

3. However, there's nothing wrong with the format of the objects. I can now make a scatterplot with matplotlib and it autoformats the datetimes as you'd expect.

   `plt.scatter(sample['posTime'].values, sample['Altitude'].values)`

   `fig = plt.gcf()`

   `fig.set_size_inches(9.5, 3.5)`

[image: formatted]

4. If you use the auto format method, you can zoom in and it will continue to automatically choose the appropriate format (but you still have to set the scale manually).

[image: autoformatted]